# List Manipulation: Add

Tags: list-manipulation

Could someone suggest some alternatives or improvements to the code below? 
What I wrote works, but there may be ways to accomplish this more elegantly with the various capabilities of the language.

The objective is that given a list of strings, assign an index number to each item and then arrange into columns, such that each column has no more than a given number of entries. Below are sample results.
[image]

Below is the code that I wrote to do this.

```
makeTOC[nameList_List, nRowsIn_Integer: 5] := 
 Module[{nNames, nRows, nCols, m1B, m1A, r1AB, toc},
  nNames = Length@nameList;
  nRows = Min[nRowsIn, nNames];
  nCols = Quotient[nNames, nRows] + If[ Divisible[nNames, nRows], 0, 1];
  m1B = ArrayReshape[nameList, {nCols, nRows}, ""] // Transpose;
  m1A = ArrayReshape[Range@Length@nameList, {nCols, nRows}, ""] // Transpose;
  r1AB = Riffle[Flatten@m1A, Flatten@m1B];
  toc = Partition[r1AB, 2 nCols]  ;
  toc
  ]
```

There is probably a better way.  One approach that didn't work, was to use ArrayReshape only once, by first combining the indices and names, and then calling ArrayReshape.  For example,

```
makeTOCalt[nameList_List, nRowsIn_Integer: 5] := 
 Module[{nNames, nRows, nCols, r1AB, toc},
  nNames = Length@nameList;
  nRows = Min[nRowsIn, nNames];
  nCols = Quotient[nNames, nRows] + If[ Divisible[nNames, nRows], 0, 1];
  r1AB = Transpose[{Range[Length@testNames], testNames}] ;
  toc = ArrayReshape[r1AB, {nCols, nRows}];
  toc
  ]
```

The alternative code is more clear, because it directly combines the indices with the names and then operates on the result. But alas, it doesn't work.

Let me know if you see areas for improvement or alternatives.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks everyone.  Your answers provided new perspectives on how to use the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
makeTOC[names_, n_] := Flatten[
    Partition[
        Thread[{Range@Length@names, names}],
        n, n, 1, {}
    ],
    {{2}, {1, 3}}
]
```

And a few examples:

```
makeTOC[testNames, 3] //TableForm
makeTOC[testNames, 5] //TableForm
makeTOC[testNames, 8] //TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Initial testing suggests that the following are equivalent, but still parsing the documentation to understand if this is true for all cases.  
                                                
Partition[Thread[{Range@Length@names, names}], UpTo[n] ]
Partition[Thread[{Range@Length@names, names}], n, n, 1, {}]

Comment: @user6546 I think it is true, I'm just not used to using UpTo.

Answer (score 4):

one another possibility

make list of names

```
list = ("name_" <> ToString[#]) & /@ Range[13]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then use `Partition` with option `UpTo` and then use `TableForm` with `Heading`

```
nRows=4;
TableForm[Partition[list,UpTo[nRows]],TableHeadings->{Range[nRows],None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

[`Multicolumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multicolumn.html) is similar to what you are trying to do except that `Multicolumn[list, cols]` uses the smallest number of rows so that all elements will be shown. That is, for a given number of columns it balances the entries per column.

```
makeTOC[nameList_List, nRowsIn_Integer: 5] := 
 Multicolumn[testNames, Ceiling[Length[nameList]/nRowsIn]]

testNames = "Name_" <> # & /@ CharacterRange["A", "J"];

makeTOC[testNames, #] & /@ {3, 5, 8, 12} //
 Column[#, Spacings -> 2] &
```

[image]

Comment: Good to know about Multicolumn.  Also, that function can be persuaded to work with rows rather than columns, So, that the following makes a table with the requested number of rows.:  makeTOC[nameList_List, nRowsIn_Integer: 5] := 
 Multicolumn[nameList, {Min[Length@nameList, nRowsIn], Automatic}]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html) that puts the indices and the names in the same string, and then reshapes the result (like your second approach, I think).

```
makeTOC[namelist_, n_] := Module[
  {numberednames = 
    MapIndexed[ToString[First@#2] <> "  " <> #1 &, namelist]},
  Transpose@
    ArrayReshape[
     numberednames, {Ceiling[Length[namelist]/n], n}] /. {0 -> Nothing}
  ]
```

Some examples:

```
makeTOC[testNames, 3] // TableForm
makeTOC[testNames, 8] // TableForm
```

[image]

[image]

Putting the indices in a string with the names means that there are going to be string formatting issues to think about (like `Name_J` being out of alignment). As you know, keeping the indices out of the strings can complicate the structure of the table, and I can't really see a way around it that isn't just paraphrasing @CarlWoll's `Flatten`ing.

If for whatever reason you wanted to use `ArrayReshape` rather than `Partition` you could do

```
makeTOC[namelist_, n_] := Flatten[
  ArrayReshape[
    Transpose[{Range@Length@#, #} &@testNames], 
      {Ceiling[Length[testNames]/n], n, 2}] /. {0, 0} -> Nothing,
  {{2}, {1, 3}}]
```

which essentially recreates @CarlWoll's method in a more verbose way.